# C struct tm time - add hours

Tags: c, time

I have `struct tm` that represents time `1900-01-01 00:00:00`. How can I add offset in hours to it? For example, I have offset in hours - value `1048621` (aprox. 119.7 years).

Comment: Convert the structure to a unified integer time-stamp, then convert the hours to the same unit as the time-stamp, and add them together. Convert back into a `tm` structure. There's really no easy or simple way to deal with time and dates.

Comment: Can I use `timegm` with `time_t` for this? Because UNIX timestamp starts at 1970.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the resulting date/time falls into the range representable by `time_t`, you can add the hours offset to `tm::tm_hour` then call `mktime` to normalize.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    struct tm t = { 0 };
    t.tm_mday = 1;  // Jan 1st 1900

    t.tm_hour = 1048621;
    if(mktime(&t) == -1) return 1;

    printf("%d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d\n",
           t.tm_year + 1900, t.tm_mon + 1, t.tm_mday,
           t.tm_hour, t.tm_min, t.tm_sec);

    return 0;
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/Kfj1Kh):

```
2019-08-17 13:00:00
```

---

[ *EDIT* ]   As pointed out in a comment, the above `mktime` call fails with MSVC. Turns out that Microsoft's `mktime` implementation does a precheck on the `tm` argument, and unconditionally fails if `tm_year < 69` before/without even looking at the other `tm` fields. While it is expected for [`mktime`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/mktime) to fail if the end date/time falls outside the [`time_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time_t) range, in particular if it is earlier than the start of the epoch (usually Jan 1st 1970), such check should normally be done *after* (re)normalization.

Below is updated code that adds range validation, and was verified to work with [gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/zK9cYT) and [msvc](https://rextester.com/YCMCC17464).

```
#include <time.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    const int tmYear1970 = 70;
    const int tmDay1970 = tmYear1970 * 365 + tmYear1970 / 4; //      25568
    const int tmHour1970 = tmDay1970 * 24;                   //     613632
    const int tmHourMax = INT_MAX - tmHour1970;              // 2146870015

    int tmHour = 1048621;
    if(tmHour < tmHour1970 || tmHour > tmHourMax) return 2;

    struct tm t = { 0 };
    t.tm_mday = 1; // Jan 1st 1900 12 AM

    t.tm_year = tmYear1970;
    t.tm_hour = tmHour - tmHour1970;
    t.tm_isdst = -1;
    if (mktime(&t) == -1) return 1;

    printf("%d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d\n",
           t.tm_year + 1900, t.tm_mon + 1, t.tm_mday,
           t.tm_hour, t.tm_min, t.tm_sec);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In Visual Studio it is not working and time is not changed after `mktime`. Return value from `mktime` is -1

Comment: @MartinPerry I edited the error checking in. [`mktime`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/mktime) is supposed to renormalize out-of-range values, and `1048621` certainly fits into an int. I'll have to take a look at MSVC's CRT sources to track this down.

Comment: @MartinPerry MSVC's `mktime` will unconditionally fail if `tm_year < 69` before even looking at the other `tm` fields, so this explains the error. Don't know that this is compliant behavior, though. Guess a workaround could be coded for MSVC with `tm_year = 70` and `tm_hour = 1048621 - magic_const`. Will edit that into the answer tomorrow.

Comment: @MartinPerry Turns out MSVC has a second quirk about `mktime` where the local DST is somehow taken into consideration even when `tm_isdst = 0`. The updated code (above) works the same in gcc without the `t.tm_isdst = -1;` line, but requires it in MSVC (or, another alternative in MSVC is to use the non-standard `_mkgmtime` instead).